# How to parallelize two nested for loops in this function?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

So I have used a profiler to test my code and it shows that this particular function takes 30% of the total running time of the code used by this function. Naturally, I tried parallelizing this function using OpenMP with no luck (in fact function becomes slower)

```
static const int nx = 64;
static const int ny = 64;
static const int nz = 64;
static const int nzk = nz / 2 + 1;

#define IMAG 1
#define REAL 0

void Function(double var1[][ncomp], double var2[], double Output[][ncomp]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {
      for (int k = 0; k < nzk; ++k) {
        for (int l = 0; l < ncomp; ++l) {
          Output[k + nzk * (j + ny * i)][l] =
              var1[k + nzk * (j + ny * i)][l] * var2[k + nzk * (j + ny * i)];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  double dummy;  // This is used so that data are not accidentally overwritten
  for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {
      for (int k = 0; k < nzk; ++k) {
        dummy = Output[k + nzk * (j + ny * i)][REAL];
        Output[k + nzk * (j + ny * i)][REAL] =
            -Output[k + nzk * (j + ny * i)][IMAG];
        Output[k + nzk * (j + ny * i)][IMAG] = dummy;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The function takes the product of the `var1` and `var2` and multiplies the output by the imaginary number `i`
I was wondering if there is a better way to implement openmp here or sort of focus on other functions instead if this isn't possible?

**EDIT:**
I am including an example that resembles my code:

```
static const int nx = 64;
static const int ny = 64;
static const int nz = 64;
static const int ncomp = 2;
static const int nzk = nz / 2 + 1;

void Function(double var1[][ncomp], double var2[], double Output[][ncomp]);

#define IMAG 1
#define REAL 0

int main() {
  fftw_complex* var1;
  var1 = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc((nx * ny * nzk) * sizeof(fftw_complex));
  memset(var1, 42, (nx * ny * nzk) * sizeof(fftw_complex));

  double* var2;
  var2 = (double*)fftw_malloc((nx * ny * nz) * sizeof(double));
  memset(var2, 42, (nx * ny * nz) * sizeof(double));

  fftw_complex* testout;
  testout = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc((nx * ny * nzk) * sizeof(fftw_complex));
  memset(testout, 42, (nx * ny * nzk) * sizeof(fftw_complex));

  Function(var1, var2, testout);

  fftw_free(testout);
  fftw_free(var1);
  fftw_free(var2);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to people in the comment I was able to actually get rid off the unnecessary nested for loops and calculate everything under a single loop as the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (nx * ny * nzk); ++i){ 
        Output[i][0] = -var1[i][1] * var2[i]; 
        Output[i][1] = var1[i][0] * var2[i]; }
```

Now this code without use of OpenMP returns the serial time `0.001752s` compared to the original code with serial time:  `0.003833s` which is great (twice as much speed up)

Now with openmp, I have the simple example:

```
for (int nThreads =1; nThreads <= 16; nThreads++){
            double start_time, run_time;
            start_time = omp_get_wtime();

            omp_set_num_threads(nThreads);  
            #pragma omp parallel for
            for (int i = 0; i < (nx * ny * nzk); ++i){ 
                Output[i][0] = -var1[i][1] * var2[i]; 
                Output[i][1] = var1[i][0] * var2[i]; }
            run_time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time;
            cout << "Threads: " << nThreads <<  " Parallel Time in s: " <<  run_time << "s\n";
    }
```

which returns the following:

```
Threads: 1 Parallel Time in s: 0.0017534s
Threads: 2 Parallel Time in s: 0.0018635s
Threads: 3 Parallel Time in s: 0.001653s
Threads: 4 Parallel Time in s: 0.001795s
Threads: 5 Parallel Time in s: 0.0017413s
Threads: 6 Parallel Time in s: 0.0016405s
Threads: 7 Parallel Time in s: 0.0016466s
Threads: 8 Parallel Time in s: 0.0018986s
Threads: 9 Parallel Time in s: 0.0017896s
Threads: 10 Parallel Time in s: 0.0017572s
Threads: 11 Parallel Time in s: 0.0017194s
Threads: 12 Parallel Time in s: 0.0018125s
Threads: 13 Parallel Time in s: 0.0033418s
Threads: 14 Parallel Time in s: 0.0021815s
Threads: 15 Parallel Time in s: 0.0023946s
Threads: 16 Parallel Time in s: 0.0028655s
```

For context, I have 6 cores so I expect 6 times as much speedup only I set up 16 threads for testing purposes that's all. But, I don't see speed up at all which maybe means openmp isn't neccessary here? Thanks

Comment: If the code works, and you are just trying to optimize it, then you should ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Re: _"`This is used so that data are not accidentally overwritten`"_ - What does that mean?  It looks like you should use `std::swap`. Also, can you please make a [mre]?

Comment: @TedLyngmo it's because I am multiplying an imaginary number ``i`` by a complex value where the output should be: real part becomes imaginary and imaginary part becomes negative times real part. Basically, I didn't wanna risk the code overwriting something or miscalculating output.

Comment: I see, but think `auto idx = k + nzk * (j + ny * i); std::swap(Output[idx][REAL], Output[idx][IMAG]); Output[idx][REAL] = -Output[idx][REAL];` would be clearer.

Comment: Sidenote: Is there a reason why you are not using `std::complex<double>`s? You can `reinterpret_cast` a `std::complex<double>*` to a `fftw_complex*`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I personally prefer fftw_malloc with fftw3 plans. I have a bunch of fft functions and it's just simpler to use fftw_malloc even though I know I could probably use reinterpret cast with '' std::complex<double>''

Comment: A `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` is even simpler than using `fftw_malloc` as I see it. No need to do manual memory management and make sure `fftw_free` is called etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But, is it significantly faster? Do I get better optimization or is it just more convenient?

Comment: I haven't noticed any difference in speed. I assume one would have to make tons of new allocations/deallocations to notice that - which one shouldn't do anyway.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The FFTW uses SIMD instructions internally and some instructions requires data to be aligned (x86-64 is fine now but it was not in the past). See: [SIMD alignment and fftw_malloc](http://www.fftw.org/doc/SIMD-alignment-and-fftw_005fmalloc.html) : "*If the array happens not to be properly aligned, FFTW will not use the SIMD extensions.*". Alignment is critical for performance.

Comment: There's a lot of complicated index calculations for what amounts to a single block of contiguous memory. I would personally avoid that, preferring instead  to compute the total size and do the calculations in a single loop. You have a potentially higher chance of the compiler vectorizing the loop in such a case. Also, since you want to swap the positions of REAL and IMAG, why not just write them in the desired location in the first loop to begin with?

Comment: @paddy I am not sure what " contiguous memory" mean really, but what you are saying sounds like may be better? Do you mind sharing an example of how to calculate the total size and do everything in a single loop? by single loop you mean no nested for loop?

Comment: Yes, I mean a single loop. Contiguous means the data is all packed together in a one-dimensional array with no gaps. You have just chosen to treat it logically as if it's multiple dimensions. There's no need in this case to have `nx` loops of `ny` loops of `nzk`, when you can have one loop of `nx * ny * nzk`. You are not using `i`, `j` or `k` for any other purpose than to compute an index. So why not just use `i`. I'm not saying it'll be more efficient, but it'll be easier to understand and it _might_ result in the compiler struggling less to optimize it.

Comment: @paddy Thanks! I will test this and post an edit with my code. I will say though ```Also, since you want to swap the positions of REAL and IMAG, why not just write them in the desired location in the first loop to begin with``` when I do that it overwrites my data and returns zeros!

Comment: I find that hard to believe. `for (int i = 0; i < nx * ny * nkz; ++i) { Output[i][0] = -var1[i][1] * var2[i]; Output[i][1] = var1[i][0] * var2[i]; }` -- this performs all the multiplications and the "swap" logic in one hit. I have no idea how you tried to write it.

Comment: 1) what @paddy has posted in the comment just above is the way to go; 2) you should have posted your attempt with OpenMP, even if it's not efficient; 3) OpenMP is no magic and doesn't gurantee any speed-up:it depends on many factors, including the kiind of algorithm, the total workload, the number of threads, and the hardware type. Here I can say that the workload is low and that the chances to get a speed-up are low too.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to think that OpenMP _might_ help here. There's 260k multiplications happening. At least the single loop form makes an easy parallel conversion with `#pragma parallel for`. I think if that's sliced up there's a fair chance it'll be an improvement even with the overhead of thread synchronization. I agree the attempt should be shown. There are some common OpenMP mistakes that can lead to poor performance, or are just incorrect. We have no way of knowing whether the OP has made such a mistake.

Comment: @paddy First of all, thanks! Your suggestion works pretty incredibly, I had no idea I could do that! I did add an edit with all the new results and a simple openmp example as well

Comment: @PierU Thanks! Yes the example paddy provided works best for me and I also included my simple openmp attempt in the edit.

Comment: The results suggest that you are not running with optimizations enabled, because the loop you're testing performs essentially a useless operation, and you should be seeing times closer to zero. Benchmarking is hard. Isolated code snippets claiming a result are to be taken with a grain of salt.

Comment: @paddy what do you mean by ```optimizations enabled```? I am running with the flags ```-lfftw3 -lm -ffast-math -fno-math-errno -march=native -Ofast -fopenmp```

Comment: @paddy I think this is working ok without openmp, at least when I look at it with my profiler the function is no longer taking so long so thanks!

Comment: Regarding the compiler arguments, we had no way of knowing what you were using until you stated it. As for the task, I've been unable to measure any appreciable gains for this calculation using OpenMP, or even slicing up the task with a custom thread pool. Artificially introducing a lot more calculation does show benefits of threading, so I think my results agree with yours. The task is simply not heavy enough to benefit from being threaded. Not at this granularity, anyway. The overhead of threading seems to counteract the gains from dividing the task between threads.

Comment: @paddy If you can add a separate answer I'd love to accept your answer since it solves my issue.

Comment: Not only the workload is low (hence the OpenMP overheads hide the benefits of the parallelization), but also the algorithm is memory-bound: the bottleneck is the transfer rate between the memory and the CPU, not the CPU itself, so that using more cores doesn't really help.